# Swift Types inside Parentheses

Tags: types, swift, parentheses

I was playing around with Swift today, and some strange types started to crop up:

```
let flip = Int(random()%2)  //or arc4random(), or rand(); whatever you prefer
```

If I type `flip` into Xcode 6 (Beta 2), the auto-complete pops up, and says `flip` is of type `(Int)` instead of `Int`.

This can easily be changed:

```
let flip : Int = Int(random()%2)
let flop = random()%2
```

Now flip and flop are of type `Int` instead of `(Int)`

Playing around with it more, these "parentheses types" are predictable and you can cause them by adding extra parentheses in any part of the variable's assignment.

```
let g = (5)      //becomes type (Int)
```

You can even cause additional parentheses in the type!

```
let h = ((5))    //becomes type ((Int))
let k = (((5)))  //becomes type (((Int)))
//etc.
```

**So, my question is:** What is the difference between these parentheses types such as `(Int)` and the type `Int`?

Comment: I tested your initial code and it works as you expected first. Doesn't matter if I use Int() or not. So, I can't reproduce your observation.

Comment: Yup. Just threw it back into a playground and it went smoothly. However, I'm still unsure about what the purpose of these parenthesis types are (as they still appear).

I'm going to edit out that intro then, and just ask my question directly.

Comment: I think it is just IDE bug. `(Int)` is same as `Int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partly it's that parentheses are meaningful.

```
let g = (5)
```

...means that `g` is to be a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Types.html) consisting of one Int, symbolized `(Int)`. It's a one-element version of `(5,6)`, symbolized `(Int,Int)`.

In general you need to be quite careful about parentheses in Swift; they can't just be used any old place. They have meaning.

However, it's also partly that the code completion mechanism is buggy. If you have a reproducible case, file a report with Apple.

Comment: "If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that element.  For example, the type of (Int) is Int, not (Int)."

Comment: Well that's the buggy part. I've also seen it the other way: I had a function that takes a tuple of two Ints, but code completion saw it as take two Ints. I've seen some other bugs in connection with type declarations too; for example, `let x = Thing?[]()` doesn't work correction.

Comment: function takes two ints : `(Int, Int) -> Void`. function takes tuple of two ints : `((Int, Int)) -> Void`. but I agree tuple is very confusing compare to Array or Optional, where just syntax sugar over library type. I can't find anything like `Tuple<Int, Int>` in library.

Comment: "Partly it's that parentheses are meaningful." You haven't demonstrated any case where it is meaningful (i.e. where code semantics are different depending on whether the parentheses are there)

Comment: "means that g is to be a tuple consisting of one Int" Is there such a thing as a tuple of one element?

Comment: @BryanChen: "function takes two ints : (Int, Int) -> Void. function takes tuple of two ints : ((Int, Int)) -> Void." These two are the same. The first function can also take a tuple of two ints; and the second one can also take two ints.

Comment: @newacct interesting, they seems have interchangeable type. but I did get compile error when I call `((Int, Int)) -> Void` with with two ints

Comment: @BryanChen: There seems to be issues with integer literals, maybe ambiguities with the type they should be inferred as (dunno, could be a bug). But if you use two int variables, it works.

Comment: Tuples containing a single element are identical to a single value of the base type, so `(Int)` is identical to `Int`, per the language specification.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, as far as I can tell. `(Int)` and `Int` are the same type; it can be written either way.