# Swift type casting and parenthesis

Tags: swift, types, casting

Both of this type casting works
**Edit**
(as written by Nate Cook this is not a real Type Casting, in Swift type casting is done with the `as` keyword. With the following call I'm initializing an Int64 with a Float parameter.)

```
anInt = Int64(aFloat)

anInt = (Int64)(aFloat)
```

First

```
    var anInt : Int64 = 0
    var aFloat : Float = 11.5

    anInt = Int64(aFloat)
    println(anInt) // this prints 11
```

Second

```
    var anInt : Int64 = 0
    var aFloat : Float = 11.5

    anInt = (Int64)(aFloat)
    println(anInt) // this prints 11
```

In the second example the main difference is that there are parenthesis around the type Int64, but I don't find any information about this syntax in the docs.

The statement `Int64(aFloat)` is a typical initializer call that creates an Int64 passing a Float as the initialization parameters. Is this correct?

What is the meaning of the parenthesis in `(Int64)(aFloat)`? Is for better readability or there is another meaning?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Types inside Parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422108/swift-types-inside-parentheses)

Comment: I've read, but this seems a more specific case. The answer and example of Thomas Kilian seems a good explanation

Comment: Not that you aren't *casting* `aFloat`, you're calling the initializer for `Int64` with a float value. Casting in Swift is done using the `as` keyword, and would fail in this case. (Your "The statement..." summary is correct, but the title and other details point in the wrong direction.)

Comment: Yes @NateCook , you are correct, it is not a type casting, as I wrote "The statement Int64(aFloat) is a typical initializer call that creates an Int64 passing a Float as the initialization parameters. Is this correct?". My first statement (at the beginning of the question) is incorrect. I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can add an arbitrary number of parentheses (e.g. `(((Int64)))`). The main reason for the parentheses is to make a cast like `(object as SomeClass).method()`

Answer (score 1):

See the duplicate question, but the short answer is that `(Int)` declares a tuple containing a single Int, which is semantically identical, per language specification, to a single Int `Int`.